# Inno Setup: List all file names in an directory

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Am trying to list all files with names in an directory, but unable to do. Is there any way to list all files with names in an directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following script shows how to list all files of a specified directory into a `TStrings` collection (in this example listed in the list box on a custom page):

```pascal
[Code]
procedure ListFiles(const Directory: string; Files: TStrings);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  Files.Clear;
  if FindFirst(ExpandConstant(Directory + '*'), FindRec) then
  try
    repeat
      if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
        Files.Add(FindRec.Name);
    until
      not FindNext(FindRec);
  finally
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
  FileListBox: TNewListBox;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
  FileListBox := TNewListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  FileListBox.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileListBox.Align := alClient;

  ListFiles('C:\SomeDirectory\', FileListBox.Items);
end;
```

Comment: And what if I would like to list all the directories as well as files? How could that be done?

Comment: @yuval, the statement `if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then` filters only files. In case when `FindRec.Attributes` contains also `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag, it is a directory.

Comment: Tried with the same script and getting the last folder name in the list box. Any Idea ?
I need all the files in the folder ?