# Using Innosetup to install to multiple dirs

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm writing an InnoSetup script to deploy software to a user's machine (default c:/programfiles) but I also want the user to be able to navigate to, say, a portable flash drive as well (like on a second page) and then have the installer load files to the HDD (programfiles) and then have it load files onto their selected flash drive - is this possible? How would I go about executing it?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do but it sounds possible to me.
As you stated you could do this with a second page where you allow the user to select a drive or a directory where some files are.
You can then iterate over all files and install them into the selected program directory you chose in the setup before.

For more information it would be good if you could provide more information but so far this is the best answer i can give you for the provided information.

Maybe this helps you along when listing up all files in a directory:
[Inno Setup: list all file names in an directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808068/inno-setup-list-all-file-names-in-an-directory)

And with this you can copy them:
[Inno setup filecopy](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filecopy)

And if you want a FolderBrowser use this:
[Pascal Scripting: BrowseForFolder](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_browseforfolder)

Comment: Thank you very much - the alternative I found, which was a waste of time imho, was having it run a second installer after & by the first.