# What is the default size of a custom page canvas area in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

What is the default size of a custom page canvas area (surface)?

This is so that I can accurately position the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to refer to `TWizardPage.Surface.Width` and `TWizardPage.Surface.Height`.

---

For an example, see the uses of `CustomSelectTasksPage.Surface` in:
[Inno Setup - Create a dynamic list of components/types from external source (file or folder contents)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37931971/850848)