# Inno setup delete only folder

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following directory structure,

```
Parent //Directory
---<XYZ> //Directory - can be any name
---File 1
---File 2
---File 3
```

I want to delete only the XYZ directory (leaving all the files) inside Parent directory during installation.

How to achieve this in inno setup script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808068/inno-setup-list-all-file-names-in-an-directory) You can find the way to get the list of files and directories.

Delete directory You can by `DelTree`